# How to use "to a large extent" in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-patterns

I formed below statements with "to a large extent". Which one is correct? and What is the most common and formal way of agreeing with something?

1. I to a large extent agree with the given statement.
2. I agree with the given statement to a large extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence: 
I to a large extent agree with the given statement.

should include commas as:
 I, to a large extent, agree with the given statement.

The second sentence is ok : 
I agree with the given statement to a large extent.

Comment: You can also put it at the beginning: *To a large extent I ...*